# Does naming objects in XAML impact anything?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Does assigning the attribute "Name" have any impact on objects in XAML?  All of the objects I want to provide a Name value for have currently have no Name value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will set the Name property on the class.  If the XAML is associated with code-behind, the XAML compiler will also expose the named elements to the code-behind (assuming that Name maps to x:Name, which is true for most WPF controls you would represent with XAML.)  You can also use x:Name explicitly if you have a class that doesn't support a Name property.

Comment: Since there was no name value to begin with, nothing is using it and that should fine right?

Comment: @4thSpace, yes, if nothing was referring to it, then not having a Name (or being given a new Name) is not a problem.  In fact, if using a pattern like MVVM, there is very little code-behind, so it's very common to not assign names to most elements in a Window or UserControl.  Names are generally only necessary in that case when using things like triggers and relative bindings.